# Deciding new limits in double integral variables change

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x dy dx$$

using $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$.

So ${\partial(x,y) \over \partial(u,v)} = -{1 \over 2}$

But how do I decide what sould be the new limits of integration in $\int \int {1 \over 2} du dv$ ?

Comment: By drawing the integrating region and having lots of practice. I know it's not what you wanted to hear, but there you go.

Comment: @5xum actually, I wanted to hear anything that can help me. If I draw it - how can I deduce the new limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$\begin{cases} u = x+y, \\[5pt] v = x-y, \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x = \dfrac{u+v}{2}, \\[5pt] y = \dfrac{u-v}{2}. \end{cases}$$
Since $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$:
$$0 < u +v < 2 \quad\text{ and }\quad 0 < u-v < u+v.$$
Reordering, and removing unnecesary bounds, you finally get:
$$u + v < 2 \quad\text{ and }\quad 0 < u-v \quad\text{ and }\quad  v>0.$$
This is the plot of the region ($u$ vs. $v$). The regions are defined by the equations above (in blue orange and green, respectively), the domain of integration being their intersection (in black). Try to obtain the new limits from there:

[image: Plot of the region]

Hint: Note that, depending on the order (first $u$ then $v$ or viceversa), you will need one integral or the sum of two.